# mybatis cannot generator using oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, generator, mybatis, ibatis

I got a `generatorConfig.xml` like this:

```
<generatorConfiguration>
    <classPathEntry location="D:\Workspace\springlt\src\main\resources\ojdbc6.jar" />

    <context id="MyBatis3" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">
        <commentGenerator>
            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true" />
        </commentGenerator>

        <jdbcConnection driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            connectionURL="myurl" userId="username"
            password="password">
        </jdbcConnection>

        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="vn.laptrinh.domain"
            targetProject="../java" />

        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="vn.laptrinh.dao.xml"
            targetProject="../java" />

        <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER"
            targetPackage="vn.laptrinh.dao" targetProject="../java" />

        <!-- <table tableName="users" domainObjectName="User"
            enableSelectByExample="false" enableDeleteByExample="false"
            enableCountByExample="false" enableUpdateByExample="false">
            <columnOverride column="id" javaType="Long" />
        </table> -->

        <table tableName="CARDUSER_MASTER" domainObjectName="CardUserMaster"
            schema="CACISISS" enableSelectByExample="false"
            enableDeleteByExample="false" enableCountByExample="false"
            enableUpdateByExample="false">
        </table>
    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

Previously, I use mysql database and I put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar` and `mybatis-generator-core-1.3.1.jar` in ..\springlt\src\main\resources folder, then use command line to `run java -jar mybatis-generator-core-1.3.1.jar -configfile generatorConfig.xml -overwrite -tables users`, project will generate `domain, xml, xmlmapper`

However when I change `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar` to `ojdbc6.jar` (I'm using oracle 11g), then I run and got bunches of errors:

```
D:\Workspace\springlt\src\main\resources>java -jar mybatis-generator-core-1.3.1.
jar -configfile generatorConfig.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception getting JDBC Dr
iver
        at org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.ConnectionFactory.getDriver(Connect
ionFactory.java:85)
        at org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(Con
nectionFactory.java:54)
        at org.mybatis.generator.config.Context.getConnection(Context.java:498)
        at org.mybatis.generator.config.Context.introspectTables(Context.java:40
8)
        at org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator.generate(MyBatisGenerator.
java:221)
        at org.mybatis.generator.api.ShellRunner.main(ShellRunner.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.mybatis.generator.internal.ObjectFactory.externalClassForName(Obj
ectFactory.java:90)
        at org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.ConnectionFactory.getDriver(Connect
ionFactory.java:82)
        ... 5 more
```

I dont' know what is the problem is. I connect to database located on server.

Any solutions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please change this:

```
<jdbcConnection driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        connectionURL="myurl" userId="username"
        password="password">
    </jdbcConnection>
```

to

```
<jdbcConnection driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        connectionURL="myurl" userId="username"
        password="password">
    </jdbcConnection>
```

and see if it is working for you

Comment: Thanks. I haven't recognized that mistake. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I had everything configured properly and realised the cause of this error can also be that the plugin is not able to find the ojdbc jar. What worked for me is to add classPathEntry in my generator file.

```
 <generatorConfiguration>    
  <classPathEntry location="/Users/adaprognotebook/lib/ojdbc6.jar"/>     
  <context id="system" >
    <plugin type="org.mybatis.generator.plugins.CaseInsensitiveLikePlugin" />
...
```